# NVIDIA Driver Update on Retina Macbook in Windows 8 on Parallels 9

Tags: drivers, macbook, nvidia-graphics-card, parallels, macbook-pro-retina

Is it possible to upgrade to the latest nvidia drivers for the retina macbook (nvidia gt 650m, 750m)? When I try this, the driver software indicates that there are no nvidia drivers on board...

Answer (score 0):

In Parallels, you don't have an 'NVidia GPU', you have a Parallels Display Adapter.
The NVidia is being used by the Mac to display an image generated by Parallels...

[image]